# I want to make use of expandlelistView to display products and the sub products

Tags: java, android

I want to make use of expandlelistView to display products and the sub products, which is the childHolder, in the childHolder, it contains a textView and an Edittext which holds the value for the product count for each sub product, the problem here is this.

1. When I input the values in the edittext, upon collapsing the group, the data is lost in the edittext.
2. The values get duplicated in the other group edittext.

3.How to save the data for later use in the Application.

The code below.

The activity layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.activities.ShelfCheckActivity">


<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The adapter class

```
public class ShelfCheckAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

ArrayList<ListItemModel> groupItem;
GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
Context context;
public LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public ShelfCheckAdapter(ArrayList<ListItemModel> groupItem, Context 
context) {
    this.groupItem = groupItem;
    this.context = context;
}

public  void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater)
{
    this.layoutInflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groupItem.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groupItem.get(groupPosition).getArrayList().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groupItem.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groupItem.get(groupPosition).getArrayList().get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View 
convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_group,null);
        groupViewHolder.groupTitle = (TextView) 
   convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewGroup);
        convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    }
    else{
        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


groupViewHolder.groupTitle.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition).getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean 
    isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();
        convertView = 
   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row_child,null);
        childViewHolder.childTitle = 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        childViewHolder.et = convertView.findViewById(R.id.productCount);

        convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);

    }
    else{
        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
  childViewHolder.childTitle.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition)
 .getChildTitles().get(childPosition));

    if (!groupItem.get(groupPosition).getArrayList()
    .get(childPosition).getValue().equals(""))
        childViewHolder.et.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition)
 .getArrayList().get(childPosition).getValue());
    else
        childViewHolder.et.setText("");

    childViewHolder.et.setOnFocusChangeListener((v, hasFocus) -> {
        if (!hasFocus){
            final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;           

  groupItem.get(groupPosition)    
  .getArrayList().get(childPosition).setValue(Caption. 
   getText().toString());
        }
    });

      return convertView;

}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
}

private class GroupViewHolder {
    public TextView groupTitle;
}

private class ChildViewHolder {
    public TextView childTitle;
    public EditText et;
}
}
```

The model class

```
public class ListItemModel {

String title;
ArrayList<EdittextValues> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

public ListItemModel(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public ArrayList<EdittextValues> getArrayList() {
    return arrayList;
}

public void setArrayList(ArrayList<EdittextValues> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}
}
```

The pojo class

```
public class EdittextValues {
String value;

public EdittextValues(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

The activity class

```
public class ShelfCheckActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private ExpandableListView expandableListView;

ShelfCheckAdapter shelfCheckAdapter;
ArrayList<ListItemModel> listItemModels;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shelf_check);

    // initializing the views
    initViews();

    // preparing list data
    //initListData();

}

/**
 * method to initialize the views
 */
private void initViews() {

    expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    initListData();
    shelfCheckAdapter = new 
    ShelfCheckAdapter(listItemModels,ShelfCheckActivity.this);

 shelfCheckAdapter
 .setInflater((LayoutInflater)
   getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    expandableListView
  .setAdapter(shelfCheckAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_store_check, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

private void initListData() {

    ArrayList<EdittextValues> edittextValues = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<String> childTitle = new ArrayList<>();
    childTitle.add("Product a");
    childTitle.add("Product b");
    childTitle.add("Product c");
    childTitle.add("Product d");
    childTitle.add("Product e");
    childTitle.add("Product f");
    childTitle.add("Product g");
    childTitle.add("Product h");
    childTitle.add("Product i");
    childTitle.add("Product j");
    childTitle.add("Product k");
    childTitle.add("Product l");

    for(int i = 0; i < childTitle.size(); i++)
    {
        edittextValues.add(new EdittextValues(""));
    }

    listItemModels = new ArrayList<>();
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    1",edittextValues,childTitle));
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    2",edittextValues,childTitle));
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    3",edittextValues,childTitle));
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    4",edittextValues,childTitle));
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    5",edittextValues,childTitle));
    listItemModels.add(new ListItemModel("Product 
    6",edittextValues,childTitle));

  }



  @Override
   public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    return false;
  }

   @Override
  public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    return false;
  }
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qswyb.png)

Comment: you have to make a model and take that model in arraylist with product and sub product. Now in oncreateviewholder() method you have to take ontextchanged() method of each textview and in that save that text in model by getting particular model from arraylist with getViewHolder().getAdapterPosition(). By using this method you can be able to use it later.

Comment: I'm about to add the code so you'll have a better look at it

Comment: yes please post your code

Comment: I've added the code with image

Comment: i've added answer below please try to check its working or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change below methods and check its working or not!

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean 
    isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row_child,null);
        childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder(convertView, groupPosition, childPosition);        
        convertView.setTag(childViewHolder);
    }
    else{
        childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
  childViewHolder.childTitle.setText(groupItem.get(groupPosition)
 .getChildTitles().get(childPosition));

      return convertView;

}
```

Another change is

```
private class ChildViewHolder {
    public TextView childTitle;
    public EditText et;

    public ChildViewHolder(View itemView, int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        super(itemView);
        childTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        et = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productCount);

        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(charSequence != null){
                      groupItem.get(groupPosition).getArrayList().get(childPosition).setValue(charSequence.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Inside the ChildviewHolder constructor the super(itemView) gives compile time error says Object() in Object cannot be applied to (android.view.View). And when i tried it without the super(itemView) it still gave the same output, duplicating the edittext

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked fine, it was able to hold the values for me, but how would i be able to check if the position is filled or empty so as to know the values to put in there